# CodePush - Releasing an iOS bundle breaks Android and vice versa

Tags: android, ios, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

Using `react-native-code-push`.

Whenever I release an iOS version (using `code-push release-react ... ios`), it breaks my Android code push. Next time I try to get an update I get the following error:

> You attempted to set the key isPending with the value true on an
>   object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.

Then, if I release an Android version, it breaks my iOS, getting this error:

> Update is invalid - A JS bundle file named "main.jsbundle" could not
>   be found within the downloaded contents. Please ensure that your app
>   is syncing with the correct deployment and that you are releasing your
>   CodePush updates using the exact same JS bundle file name that was
>   shipped with your app's binary.

It's very strange and the documentation doesn't say anything about collisions between the two platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup an app for each platform

`code-push app add [name]-ios`

`code-push app add [name]-android`

i think the `code-push release-react [app-name] [platform] ...` the platform argument only tells the react-native bundler what entry file to use (index.ios.js or index.android.js) it doesnt work as "install only on ios"

Comment: Hi there, does update native file of one platform break the other one in codepush, I have release the android version, but not the ios yet, and I need to install a pod, would that affect the android one in anyway!!